# Creating highchart line graph with Date and time

Tags: r, ggplot2, highcharts, tidyverse

I want to create a simple highchart line graph with my [my data file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/nulj8wqfifn1gxl/Moisture%20kurokawa.csv?dl=0) .
So first I changed my data, so that R recognizes the date and time.

```
library("tidyverse")
library("ggplot")
library("highcharter")
Moisture_kurokawa <- read_csv("~/Data/Moisture kurokawa.csv")

 mutate(Moisture_kurokawa, 
   timestamp = lubridate::mdy_hms(sprintf("%s %s", Date, Time))) %>% 
     select(-Date, -Time) %>% 
      gather(W, value, -timestamp) -> moisture_long
```

So after this I tried to create a simple highchart so , I tried

```
hchart(moisture_long, "line", hcaes(x = timestamp, y = value, group = W))
```

I get the graph but its says no data to display. Any help would be really appreciated.

Thank you.

Result image:

[image]

Comment: shouldn't it be ggplot2? Also, your mutate command is throwing an error for me: `Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘select’ for signature ‘"tbl_df"’
In addition: Warning message:
 24 failed to parse.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to convert `timestamp` to character:

```
mutate(Moisture_kurokawa, 
 timestamp = lubridate::mdy_hms(sprintf("%s %s", Date, Time))) %>% 
 select(-Date, -Time) %>% 
 gather(W, value, -timestamp) -> moisture_long

moisture_long$timestamp <- as.character(moisture_long$timestamp)
hchart(moisture_long, type="line", hcaes(x=timestamp, y=value, group = W))
```

A better solution is:

```
library("tidyverse")
library("highcharter")
Moisture_kurokawa <- read_csv("./Moisture kurokawa.csv") %>%
  na.omit() %>%
  mutate(timestamp = lubridate::mdy_hms(sprintf("%s %s", Date, Time)))

hc <- highchart(type="stock")
for (k in names(Moisture_kurokawa)[3:7]) {
  hc <- hc_add_series_times_values(hc=hc, dates=Moisture_kurokawa$timestamp, 
            values=pull(Moisture_kurokawa, k), name = k)
}
hc
```

[image]

Comment: SandriThank you very much. I just started learning highchart. I didnt understand this line "for (k in names(Moisture_kurokawa)[3:7])". If you have time please let me know the usage of this line

Comment: @MrGoodNews `names(Moisture_kurokawa)[3:7]` is the vector with the names of the variables to plot (`W3`, `W5`, etc)